# Backing up private emails to Gmail

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail

I am trying to backup emails from a private domain to Gmail. Am doing this using Outlook 2013 where i have configured my newly created Gmail account. So i copied emails from the profile to Gmail profile folder per folder ("Inbox" to "Inbox","Sent" to "Sent Mails"). Outlook is not synchronizing any more but i have less item count in Gmail on web(3462 Inbox) than email items i copied into Gmail in outlook (5825). Outlook cant sync anymore yet i dont want to miss any email.
Where would the problem be and what should i do to ensure the email counts are the same?

Thanks

Comment: Am I correct to assume, that both accounts, are currently setup as IMAP?

Comment: Yes, they are both IMAP profiles

Comment: How many did you attempt to synchronize at once?

Comment: just one account on each computer. I have five laptops, each with one email IMAP profile for our domain and the newly created Gmail profile. I have not achieved a full sync on the three that i have tried so far. I always have less items on web yet outlook is not synchronizing anymore

Comment: I asked how many emails did you attempt to synchoronize at once.  If you attempted to synchoronize 5825 emails, in a single operation, its going to take awhile.

Comment: I copied the entire Inbox (5825) to Gmail Inbox, left the machine on at night ith a stable intenet connection but when i logged into Gmail, only 3462 had synchronized. Outlook doesnt seen to synchronize. It says "Sychronizing" for about a minute but nothing happens next.